# reorder csv by second column, case sensitive

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, csv

I have a nice long list of order IDs followed by their serial numbers in a csv file (OID,SN).  I need to sort the list by serial number and it uses base58, so upper case letters come before lower case.

Base58: 123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz

Just doing

```
 IEnumerable<string> query =
    from line in serialNumbers
    let x = line.split(',')
    orderby x[1]
    select x[0] + "," + x[1];

 string[] temp = query.ToArray();
```

orders it alphabetically, but not in Base58 order.  How would I achieve that?  Using C#.

Comment: Check this link - [SQL-Ordering](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQL-Ordering-Operators-050af19e). Refer **OrderBy - Comparer** section. This might give you some hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom comparer, e.g. :

```
    class Base58Comparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
                return 0;
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, null))
                return -1;
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                return 1;

            int minLen = Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < minLen; i++)
            {
                // comparison based on ASCII value
                int comp = x[i].CompareTo(y[i]); 
                if (comp != 0)
                    return comp;
            }
            return x.Length - y.Length;
        }
    }
```

Then you can pass it to `OrderBy` method, e.g. :

```
var query = serialNumbers.Select(line => line.Split(','))
                         .OrderBy(x => x[1], new Base58Comparer())
                         .Select(x => x[0] + "," + x[1]);
```